# Getting errors when copying exact code from Codecademy

Tags: python

So I am completely new to any programming language and really want to learn it this time (multiple attempts) and these things aren't making it any better. I must be doing something completely simple completely wrong. [image: This picture] shows my example.

Taking code from codecademy and putting it directly into the IDE creates errors. I am using the 2.7 interpreter as that is what codecademy uses as well. I tried indents but nothing so far. Anyone care to blow my mind on how simple a fix this is?

Comment: Please paste the actual code here instead of taking the screen shot if screen shot does not gives any more information.

Comment: If you're using Python 2.7 why is there a reference to 3.4 in your project? The error you're seeing happens when you use 2-style print statements in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Python 3.4. Figured it out from the interpreter selected by Eclipse. Try changing the interpreter to 2.7. It should work.

Comment: Python 2: https://repl.it/Ba36/0. Python 3: https://repl.it/Ba35/0.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the screen shot, you are trying to do:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> print '%s/%s/%s' % (now.year, now.month, now.day)
2015/12/24
```

And it actually works on my client. (Python 2.7) I cannot see your error clearly but probably it is because you are (for some reason) trying to run it with Python 3.